# Unity disappear after autoremove

Tags: unity, launcher

First of all: I have Ubuntu 12.04, my nvidia driver doesn't properly works with my gforce 310m, and I have no advance knowledge in linux.

I was trying to reinstall python... so as a first step I write in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove python
```

It toke a while to finish. And suddenly when it finished my Unity disappear, so my application launcher and the graphics were pretty lame. I restart ubuntu but things were pretty much the same.

Now I can only:
1) launch Nautilius (the file manager) through `F3`
2) launch Chrome through Nautilius
3) I can access to any file with Nautilius.

I don't know how to open a Terminal windows. I had tried `Ctr`+`Alt`+`T` but doesn't work. I had tried to start with an old ubuntu version but cannot log in. I can't start TTY1 with `Ctl`+`Alt`+`F1` because the screen just turns off (there is no prompt). I can't even change windows with `Alt`+`tab`

I had opened the terminal when I open .sh files through Nautilius, but the terminal open and close really quickly

So, my question are:

1) How do I fix this mess?

2) How can I open a terminal window from Nautilius?

3) After I manage to open a terminal windows is it ok to command `unity --reset`?

I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Jorge M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select the recovery mode at boot, drop to the root shell, and try installing the `ubuntu-desktop` package.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If that doesn't work, just backup important data, and reinstall.

I don't have the default installation of Ubuntu, but for reference, here is what that command you've used does:

```
~$ sudo apt-get -s autoremove python
[sudo] password for hp: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libpython3.2 python3 python3-minimal python3-uno python3.2 python3.2-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python3-doc python3-tk python3.2-doc binfmt-support
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  aisleriot apparmor apport apport-gtk aptdaemon apturl apturl-common
  autotrash bluez bluez-alsa bluez-gstreamer checkbox checkbox-qt
  command-not-found compiz compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-main
  compiz-plugins-main-default compizconfig-backend-gconf
  compizconfig-settings-manager deja-dup duplicity evolution-data-server
  firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support foomatic-db-compressed-ppds
  gconf-editor gconf2 gdebi gdebi-core gedit gksu gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-control-center gnome-media gnome-menus gnome-orca gnome-sudoku
  gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-share gstreamer0.10-gconf
  hplip hplip-data ibus ibus-pinyin ibus-table indicator-datetime
  indicator-power intel-microcode jockey-common jockey-gtk
  landscape-client-ui-install language-selector-common language-selector-gnome
  launchpad-integration libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
  libcompizconfig0 libfolks-eds25 libgksu2-0 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0
  libgnome2-common libgweather-3-0 libgweather-common libmetacity-private0
  libpurple-bin libreoffice-gnome light-themes lsb-release metacity
  metacity-common microcode.ctl nautilus-share network-manager-gnome
  nvidia-common nvidia-settings-304-updates onboard oneconf openprinting-ppds
  printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-ptouch
  printer-driver-pxljr printer-driver-sag-gdi printer-driver-splix
  pybootchartgui python python-appindicator python-apport python-apt
  python-apt-common python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python-aptdaemon.pkcompat python-brlapi python-cairo python-central
  python-chardet python-compizconfig python-configglue python-crypto
  python-cups python-cupshelpers python-dateutil python-dbus python-debian
  python-debtagshw python-defer python-dirspec python-egenix-mxdatetime
  python-egenix-mxtools python-eyed3 python-gconf python-gdbm python-gi
  python-gi-cairo python-gnomekeyring python-gnupginterface python-gobject
  python-gobject-2 python-gst0.10 python-gtk2 python-httplib2 python-ibus
  python-imaging python-keyring python-launchpadlib python-lazr.restfulclient
  python-lazr.uri python-libproxy python-libxml2 python-louis python-mako
  python-markupsafe python-notify python-oauth python-openssl
  python-packagekit python-pam python-pexpect python-piston-mini-client
  python-pkg-resources python-problem-report python-protobuf python-pyatspi2
  python-pycurl python-pyinotify python-renderpm python-reportlab
  python-reportlab-accel python-serial python-simplejson python-smbc
  python-software-properties python-speechd python-support python-twisted-bin
  python-twisted-core python-twisted-names python-twisted-web
  python-ubuntu-sso-client python-ubuntuone-client
  python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol python-uno python-virtkey python-wadllib
  python-xapian python-xdg python-xkit python-zeitgeist python-zope.interface
  rhythmbox rhythmbox-mozilla screen-resolution-extra sessioninstaller
  software-center software-center-aptdaemon-plugins software-properties-common
  software-properties-gtk system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev totem totem-mozilla
  totem-plugins ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-sso-client
  ubuntu-sso-client-gtk ubuntu-standard ubuntu-system-service ubuntuone-client
  ubuntuone-installer ufw unattended-upgrades unity unity-2d unity-common
  unity-lens-applications update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier
  update-notifier-common usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk xdiagnose
  xul-ext-ubufox zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython3.2 python3 python3-minimal python3-uno python3.2 python3.2-minimal
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 212 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Note, for example, that it removes `gnome-terminal`, which is why you aren't able to launch it.

Comment: Thank you very much @mikewhatever!!!
What I did:
1) `Ctr`+`Alt`+`F1` -> Black screen
2) `Ctr`+`Alt`+`F7` -> Desktop
3) `Ctr`+`Alt`+`F1` -> I can see a terminal (6 terminals)
4) $ `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
5) restart
Thanks again!